# Reduce brightness on background without 1 child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to reduce the background brightness when 1 DIV element is shown. However i manage to reduce the background using `filter: brightness(0.5)` but then the DIV element have reduced brightness as well

I've try it to use `:not()` operator but not successfully

This is how the css looks like:

```
#app {
  width: 360px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:not(.getting-started-overlay) {
    filter: brightness(0.5);
  }
}
```

And this is how the DOM structure looks like:
[image: Dom structure]

How not to apply brightness on div with class `getting-started-overlay`

Answer (score -1):

Add a space to your rule:`& :not(.getting-started-overlay)` to target the children of #app instead of #app

EDIT
You might be able to make use of the :empty pseudo class, which targets elements with no children, though in your case, your #app is the element that holds the properties you want changing.

Why not add a .empty class to the app and add append your populating function with a classlist.remove('empty')

Comment: Yeah but in that case the filter have been added to all childrens instead to the #app it self, my point is to add it for `#app` and turn it off for 1 children